# How to enforce a asynctask in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have meet a problem, I call a new Asynctask inside another Asynctask, the result is that when call
the second Asynctask, the thread is blocked, how can force to run the Asynctask? Thanks.

Comment: Why starting async from async? Do it in one AsyncTask only

Comment: Start the next asynctask in the onPostExecute of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by implementing an interface in your AsyncTask #1 and adding a callback routine to the activity which executes it. Something like

MyAsyncTask.java

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public interface OnTaskCompletedListener {
        void onTaskCompleted();
    }

    private Activity mActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void attach(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void detach() {
        mActivity = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing) {
        if (mActivity != null) mActivity.onTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAsyncTask.OnTaskCompletedListener {

    private MyAsyncTask mTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mTask!= null) {
            mTask.attach(this);
        } else {
            mTask = new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mTask!= null)) mTask.detach();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted() {
        mTask = null;
        // execute another task from here
    }
}
```

In example above includes attach() and detach() methods to handle activity re-creation on orientation or other configuration changes. It may be omitted in AsyncTask is implemented as an inner class.

Main idea: AsyncTask finishes and passes execution to a callback routine in the activity. Anything could be performed inside onTaskCompleted() - either calling a different or the same AsyncTask again

Comment: Although this is very nice code it does not help the OP as he wants to start other AsyncTasks in doInBackground as far as i understood.